# Function fired multiple times at once on multiple websocket event message

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

Listening to a websocket server, I can get multiple events at the same time, which triggers a same async function multiple times at once.

Here is the log:

```
{
  d: '{"t":1924698,"p":"1541.86", "T":1662043735929}'
}
{
  d: '{"t":1924699,"p":"1541.86","T":1662043735955}' // <-- At the same timestamp
}
{
  d: '{"t":1924700,"p":"1541.21","T":1662043735955}' // <-- At the same timestamp
}
{
  d: '{"t":1924701,"p":"1540.91","T":1662043735955}' // <-- At the same timestamp
}
```

1. 1st event `"t":1924698` is sent solo
2. 2nd event is sent along with 2 others: `1924699`, `1924700`, `1924701`

Once a 2nd event arrives with 3 messages, it fires up a method 3 times at once, which is not OK. How could I limit my method execution once per event?

For example from 2nd event it should execute only the last item, but `event.length` is `undefined`.

```
connection.on('message', async event => {
  console.log(event)
  const data = JSON.parse(event.d)

  await trigger(data.p)
})
```

Comment: `event` is not an array, why should `event.length` be defined? Maybe you mean `event.d.length`?

Comment: No, I need to get all those 3 messages in one array, instead I got them as a object separately. `event.length` is just to show it's not an array

Comment: How is the client sending the messages?

Comment: No idea, it's coming from a binance websocket